# Service worker update not working?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a nginx hosted Jekyll site.

I have made several changes to my site, update package version and changed my javascript to update the service worker. However my changes are still not reflecting in chrome;

**main.js**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js', {scope: 'sw-test'}).then(function(registration) {
// registration worked
console.log('Registration succeeded.');
    registration.update();
}).catch(function(error) {
// registration failed
console.log('Registration failed with ' + error)
 });
}
```

**sw.js**

```
var PRECACHE = 'precache-{{site.version}}';
var RUNTIME = 'runtime';

// A list of local resources we always want to be cached.
var PRECACHE_URLS = [
    './',
    '/index.html',
    '/assets/css/main.css',
    '/assets/js/vendor/modernizr-custom.js',
    '/assets/js/bundle.js'
];

// The install handler takes care of precaching the resources we always need.
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(PRECACHE)
      .then(cache => cache.addAll(PRECACHE_URLS))
      .then(self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// The activate handler takes care of cleaning up old caches.
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  var currentCaches = [PRECACHE, RUNTIME];
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return cacheNames.filter(cacheName => !currentCaches.includes(cacheName));
    }).then(cachesToDelete => {
      return Promise.all(cachesToDelete.map(cacheToDelete => {
        return caches.delete(cacheToDelete);
      }));
    }).then(() => self.clients.claim())
  );
});

// The fetch handler serves responses for same-origin resources from a cache.
// If no response is found, it populates the runtime cache with the response
// from the network before returning it to the page.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  // Skip cross-origin requests, like those for Google Analytics.
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(cachedResponse => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return cachedResponse;
        }

        return caches.open(RUNTIME).then(cache => {
          return fetch(event.request).then(response => {
            // Put a copy of the response in the runtime cache.
            return cache.put(event.request, response.clone()).then(() => {
              return response;
            });
          });
        });
      })
    );
  }
});
```

**Chrome Screenshot** 
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOjJ6.png)

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Try to unregister your `sw.js` and also clear your site data in `application` tab

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx config is most likely setting some caching headers on the SW script. When that's the case, the browser returns the old version from its local cache skipping network completely.